# Iterate through late bound objects enum(s)

Tags: .net

```
Public Class ScoringStrategyEntity

    Public Enum TotalingMethodType
        Weighted_Share
        Multiply_Components
    End Enum

Private _TotalingMethod As TotalingMethodType
    Public Property TotalingMethod() As TotalingMethodType
        Get
            Return _TotalingMethod
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As TotalingMethodType)
            _TotalingMethod = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Dim ScoringStrategy As Object = Activator.CreateInstance("MyDll", "MyDll.ScoringStrategyEntity").Unwrap()

For Each Enum In ScoringStrategy.TotalingMethodType

Next
```

Comment: Right - so that is code; what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "how can I get the available enum values from a `Type`?", then (using C# syntax purely for the example; the *approach* should work in VB):

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ScoringStrategy.TotalingMethodType));
```